# Trying to Get the Base Address of wow64cpu.dll

Tags: winapi

GetModuleHandle and LoadLibrary fails with ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND, also EnumProcessModules doesn't show it. What else can I do, and I am sure it is loaded.

Comment: Feature, not a bug.  A 32-bit process cannot enumerate the 64-bit modules that implement the WoW (Windows on Windows) emulator that allows running 32-bit processes on a 64-bit OS.  Only an external 64-bit process could observe them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up manually switching the CPU to x64 mode. After that I get 64 bit TEB like this:

```
mov eax, gs:[0x30]
```

from TEB, I get the PEB, and using InLoadOrderModuleList member of it, searched for wow64cpu.dll, after storing what I want, switched CPU back to x86 mode.

Comment: push _cs      call$+5      add dword [esp], 5      retf       will switch cpu to the x64 mode immediately after execution.

Comment: Are you trying to reinvent [IsWow64Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684139.aspx)?

Comment: @IInspectable No, I am using manual syscalls but since my process is x86, they go through wow64 layer, so if someone hooks some functions on wow64cpu.dll, he can intercept all of my calls. So I am checking the integrity of some parts of wow64cpu.dll, to be sure it is original. btw since I can already switch to x64 mode, I will probably implement these syscalls in x64 so they don't get through wow64 layer.